# How to find the intersection of two splines using the QR algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

The problem is to find the intersection point of two splines given by cubic splines of the form:

> $$S_{i}(x) = A(x-x_{i})^3 + B(x-x_{i})^2 + C(x -x_{i}) + D$$
> Where A, B, C, D are the coefficients.

Given two splines on the segment [a, b] ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics))):

First: $S_{0}^{1}(x), S_{1}^{1}(x) \dots S_{n}^{1}(x)$

Second: $S_{0}^{2}(x), S_{1}^{2}(x) \dots S_{k}^{2}(x)$

I came up with this algorithm:

1. Find the matrix of coefficients of the system of splines equations.
2. Find the characteristic equation of this matrix.
3. Find eigenvalues of the matrix using QR algorithm.
4. For each eigenvalue, find the corresponding eigenvector.

Next, I have difficulties with the fact that I do not understand how to use the found eigenvectors to find the intersection points of splines.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, I added some explanations and a link to wikipedia

Comment: To find the intersection of splines $S$ and $T$ you set $S=T$ and solve $S-T=0$. That's not what you're being asked to do in this question though.